# having issues reading in files within a folder C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am currently working on a project that requires the assessment of mystery text files, and cross referencing them with signatures that are provided to me.
one issue I am facing is that we have gone over reading in files from a folder within the projects folder. (I'm using Visual Studios 2010)
I am provided with a simple 'data.txt' file, that contains an integer representing the number of file names of signatures; followed by that many signatures, then another integer representing the number of mystery texts; followed by that many mystery texts.
my question is, how does one read in a file, from a path given to them within another text document?
the 'data.txt' file is as follows:

```
13
signatures/agatha.christi.stats
signatures/alexandre.dumas.stats
signatures/brothers.grim.stats
signatures/charles.dickens.stats
signatures/douglas.adams.stats
signatures/emily.bronte.stats
signatures/fyodor.dostoevsky.stats
signatures/james.joyce.stats
signatures/jane.austen.stats
signatures/lewis.caroll.stats
signatures/mark.twain.stats
signatures/sir.arthur.conan.doyle.stats
signatures/william.shakespeare.stats
5
documents/mystery1.txt
documents/mystery2.txt
documents/mystery3.txt
documents/mystery4.txt
documents/mystery5.txt
```

one of the signature files is as follows(don't ask why my prof decided to use .stats, because I have no clue):

```
agatha christie

4.40212537354

0.103719383127

0.0534892315963
1
0.0836888743

1.90662947161
```

I cannot change the files, nor can I change the area in which they are saved.
I can easily read in the 'data.txt' file but cannot seem to find the signature files at all.
any help would be appreciated. 
once I read in the signatures, I plan on saving them as structs in an array so I can reference them later in the project to compare them to the signatures of the mystery texts.
this program is using namespace std, if that matters to anyone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ptic12
your answer helped a lot, i managed to edit/manipulate it to get what i needed out of it.
i created a class for signatures to make it a bit more simple.
this code is written rather simply, and its longer than it needs to be, but it works, later in the project i plan on 'slimming down' a little bit

there are a few things missing from this of course, but it would be a long post if i included them

```
vector<Signature> MakeSignatures(string DataFile)
{
    string SigFile="", MystFile="";
    int NumSig=0, NumMystery=0;
    ifstream infile(DataFile);// opens data.txt
    infile >> NumSig;
    vector<Signature> SigStorage;//creates a vector in which to store signature objects
    for(int i=0; i <NumSig; i++)
    {
        infile >> SigFile;
        Signature Sig(SigFile);
        SigStorage.push_back(SigFile);
    }
    infile >> NumMystery;
    for(int i=0; i < NumMystery; i++)
    {
        infile >> MystFile;
        //not quite done here yet
            //large part of project will be called here
    }

    return SigStorage;
}
```

and the constructor in the Signature class's .cpp

```
Signature::Signature(string SigFile)
{
    ifstream in(SigFile);
    while(!in.eof())
    {
        getline(in, AuthName); //gets author name
        in >> AverageWord; //get next 5 floats 
        in >> TypeToken;
        in >> HapaxLego;
        in >> AverageNumber;
        in >> SentenceCom;
    }

}
```

hopefully this will help anyone who needs the same sort of help i did.
(didn't really help that the data.txt included a misspelled path, took a while to figure that one out)

Answer (score 0):

Example as reading doubles.

```
File *file;
file = std::fopen(filename.c_str(), "r+b");

std::fread(&/*variableName*/, sizeof(double), 1, file);
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your directory structure is as follows:

```
the_program
data.txt
signatures/...
documents/...
```

Then it should be straightforward to read the files:

```
std::ifstream in("data.txt");
std::vector<std::string> files;
int num_files;
in >> num_files;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < num_files; ++i) {
    std::string file;
    in >> file;
    files.push_back(file);
}

// read mystery filenames

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it;
for (it = files.begin(); it != files.end(); ++it) {
    std::ifstream sig(it->c_str());

    // sig is your signature file. Read it here
}
```